# How to parse response of Web service in Ios?

Tags: ios, parsing, swift4, alamofire

How to parse response of Web service in Ios?

[Here is the Response of my web service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YhDY.png)

i already know how to parse json response by using alamofire but how to parse this response and get value in array?

[Here is my tried code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC2FQ.png)

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code as text, rather than as an image and describe the result you are getting, including any error codes

Comment: @Vishwa, Just saw your edited comment. you are using 'SWXMLHash' framework. I haven't worked on it. But found one blog 'leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift'. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do XML Parsing using `XMLParser`.

Below is the code in Swift:

```
class MyParser : NSObject, XMLParserDelegate{

    var elementName: String = String()
    var arrStr: [String] = []

    func parseXML(xmlString : String){
        if let xmlData = xmlString.data(using: .utf8){
            let parser = XMLParser(data: xmlData)
            parser.delegate = self;
            parser.parse()
        }
    }

    // MARK:- XMLParserDelegate callbacks
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
        self.elementName = elementName
    }

    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
        let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if (!data.isEmpty) {
            if self.elementName == "string" {
                arrStr.append(data)
            }
        }
    }
}

let xmlString = "<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org.2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org.2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"htp://tempuri.org\"><string>4300</string><string>4200</string></ArrayOfString>"

let parse = MyParser()
parse.parseXML(xmlString: xmlString)
print(parse.arrStr)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Vishwa, Just saw your edited comment. you are using 'SWXMLHash' framework. I haven't worked on it. But found one blog 'https://leaks.wanari.com/2016/08/24/xml-parsing-swift/'. Hope this will help.